# ImageView not showing in linear layout that is inside a scrollview

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I am trying to have two scrollable items inside my scrollview so I put a linear layout into the scroll view and inside the linear layout I put an imageview and a textview. The textview shows up but the imageview does not. What is the issue here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="@dimen/layout_padding"
    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/layout_padding"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_text"
        style="@style/NameStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/star_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/yellow_star"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bio_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_picture"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/layout_margin"
                android:contentDescription="@string/profile_picture"
                tools:srcCompat="@mipmap/image" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bio_text"
                style="@style/NameStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                android:text="@string/bio" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The `tools:srcCompat` attribute should have the `app` prefix instead; i.e., `app:srcCompat`.

Comment: It maybe possible If you are not setting an Image to `profile_picture` at runtime then it will not show .. Because you are using `tools:srcCompat` ..

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I was missing this line: app:srcCompat="@mipmap/image"

I feel dumb